# Sql Query Plugin in Dokuwiki not updating

Tags: mysql, dokuwiki

I am using the sql query plugin in dokuwiki to generate a table from values in a mysql data base. The query works fine but it does not update when the record in the mysql table change. For example new records are not displayed even if you refresh the page. I have tried to clear cache and still no luck.

Anyone know a work around